# Stats window located at the bottom of the container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I put a WebGL plot into a div container. Everything works except the Stats window which is displaying below the WebGL window.

Here what I get :

[image]

my code :

```
<html>
<head>
        <style>
#container{ 
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 700px;
        height: 700px;
           }    
        </style>
</head>


<body>

...

<div id="container">
</div> 

<script>

if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

var container, stats;
var camera, controls, scene, renderer;
var cross;
var width = 700, height = 700;

init();
animate();

function init() {

        // Define container
        container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

// Add renderer to container
  container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  // Add stats
  stats = new Stats();
  stats.domElement.style.position = 'relative';
  stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
  container.appendChild( stats.domElement );
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

For having a Stats window at the left top of the container, I have to add :

```
stats.domElement.style.bottom = '700px';
```

How to put naturally the Stats window at the left top of the container ? i.e without this trick.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check in the dom debugger if the stats are in the expected container and if there are no other css automatically added by the library ?

Comment: How can I check this with google chrome dom debugger to see if stats are in expected container ?

Comment: ok, I got the solution : put stats into nested div with position absolute and z-index = 1 and another outside div for renderer with position relative and z-index = 0 . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you can use basically two ways to get it.

the first: prepend the stats to the **#container** element, inserting it as child of **body** element and use some css in order to set it as a block relative to the body.

the second: keep statistics as they are and add this css

```
.yourStatsClass {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```